# UPDATE columns different tables with 2 Where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have some problem with UPDATE statement with 2 Where clause.

I want update **StatoBloccato**,**Aperto**,**OrarioApertura**,**OrarioChiusura** only day called **Lun** and **IDRoom = 1**

But this UPDATE change values for all days.

```
UPDATE room
INNER JOIN giorni ON (room.IDRoom = giorni.FKRoom)
SET StatoBloccato = false, 
Aperto = true, 
OrarioApertura = '09:00:00', 
OrarioChiusura = '18:00:00' 
WHERE room.IDRoom = 1 AND Nome LIKE 'Lun%';
```

There are 2 tables: Room , Giorni.

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3777a39/2/0)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. AND i am puzzled why you would attempt to set staoblocatto,OrarioApertura and OrarioChiusura to their starting values. Setting Aperto = true works as expected with only 1 row updated,

Comment: P.Salmon, in my case all rows as been updated :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work when I try it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5c1f57d188f3752b6adf805ab0a07a7f).

The specific query is:

```
UPDATE room r JOIN
       giorni g
       ON r.IDRoom = g.FKRoom
SET r.StatoBloccato = false, 
    g.Aperto = true, 
    g.OrarioApertura = '09:00:00', 
    g.OrarioChiusura = '18:00:00' 
WHERE r.IDRoom = 1 AND g.Nome LIKE 'Lun%';
```

Although this should be equivalent to your query, this uses qualifies *all* column names, so it is clear what table they are coming from.

Comment: BOOM! solved! Thank you so much Gordon! can you explain me where is my error? I need to understand. thx!

Comment: @TechSpot . . . I don't think the code you posted really had an error.  It also seems to work in the fiddle.

Comment: your query update all rows of StatoBloccato. I need to update the only one, like Aperto. I dont know why it doesn't work. Can you have a look please?

Comment: @TechSpot . . . Not at all.  The values of `StatoBloccato` all start out as `false`, so the `update` really doesn't do anything.  If you set the value to `true` in the `update`, you will see exactly one value change.